# Can I use a pre-defined tuple for dynamic tuple unpacking in for loops?

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples, python-3.7, iterable-unpacking

I am currently working on building a piece of code that is composing business objects from tuples that it has been given by the data source I am using. Since these tuples may vary in length and their naming, I want to insert a pre-defined tuple into the for loop.

```
class_attributes = ("_id", "_first_name", "_last_name")
for class_attributes in answer:
        # I would want to access them dynamically in here, instead Python is using "class_attributes" as a local variable inside the for loop
```

The piece of code from above usually fetches the tuple dynamically, resulting in different arguments and lengths of the tuple, therefore copying the line of code into the for loop is not feasible.

Comment: yeah, u can feth each item dynamically

Comment: How do you intend to use the tuple? What is the end result?

Comment: try `for i in range(len(class_attributes)): print(class_attributes[i])`

Comment: @Mohammad In the place where I would normally include "for (id, first_name, last_name) in answer:", I want to insert a tuple dynamically, so that I am not bound to those attributes.

Comment: @FynnMehrens The best solution I could think of is using default dict instead of tuples. What you are trying to do might be possible but is not very recommended. Instead, using dicts is the way to go when you have an unknown number of variables.

Comment: @FynnMehrens A much better approach would be to wrap the tuples in an [adapter class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) so that the fields can be accessed using a common interface (i.e. with any missing fields returning appropriate default values).

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand, but maybe [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.namedtuple) are an alternative (defaults are possible)?

Answer (score -1):

The `for` loop you show loops over the elemments in `answer` and assigns them to a variable named `class_attributes`, overwriting the previous assignment of the list of attributes to that variable.

If you don't mean this, I don't understand the question

```
>>> answers = [(1,'Guido', 'van Rossum'), (2, 'Tim', 'Peters')]
>>> for _id, _first_name, _last_name in answers:
...     print(_id, _first_name, _last_name)
...
1 Guido van Rossum
2 Tim Peters
```